# How to perform SVD of a matrix with symbols?

Tags: matrices, matrix-decomposition, svd

Let's assume that we have the following matrix:

\begin{pmatrix} 0& 2& 3& 4a& 5a\\
6& 7& 1& 8a& 9a\end{pmatrix}

Can we perform SVD on this matrix and get the output in function of $a$?

Comment: Yes, but it won't be a nice function.

Comment: [Here is the WA output](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=SVD+%7B%7B0%2C2%2C3%2C4a%2C5a%7D%2C%7B6%2C7%2C1%2C8a%2C9a%7D%7D) for the SVD. If you're only after the singular values, then you can at least [get something readable](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=norm+%7B%7B0%2C2%2C3%2C4a%2C5a%7D%2C%7B6%2C7%2C1%2C8a%2C9a%7D%7D).

Comment: Maybe it helps to write it as ${\bf M_1} + a{\bf M_2}$

Comment: @Omnomnomnom a is a real number (the solution is assuming that a is complex).

Comment: @mathreadler that way the SVD can be performed on which manner?

Comment: We can do SVD on $\bf M_1$ and $\bf M_2$ and by continuity the SVD shall be some smooth function relating these two depending on $a$. Then we can solve it for some different values of $a$ and do regression.

Comment: @JohnKarimov [Not much changes](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=SVD%5B%7B%7B0%2C2%2C3%2C4%7Ca%7C%2C5%7Ca%7C%7D%2C%7B6%2C7%2C1%2C8%7Ca%7C%2C9%7Ca%7C%7D%7D%5D) even if we assume that $a \geq 0$.

Comment: @mathreadler please can you provide a documentation for "continuity the SVD shall be some smooth function relating these two depending on  ". i guess it would help a lot. Thank you very much.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom please can you provide me a documentation on how to elaborate this (or even what should i look for to do it in Matlab or python)? Thanks very much.

Comment: @JohnKarimov If you're using Matlab, just declare $a$ as a symbol with `syms a` and compute the SVD using the `svd` command.

Comment: @JohnKarimov I don't have reference to any book that says it, but I am sure that in one of the courses I've taken we learned that functions of matrices where elements vary smoothly will also have factorizations with elements varying smoothly. Smooth functions are oftentimes well enough approximable by other smooth functions so that exact calculation like Wolfram tries is obviously unnecessarily expensive. Are you also interested in regressions?

Comment: @mathreadler In fact my goal is to perform SVD on the matrix shown in the post, i'm not a mathematician that's why i'm still trying to figure out how to do that.The idea that you've proposed looks awesome to use M1 + aM2. I'm still wondering how to do it. What about regressions?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Alright! I'm checking that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seeing that the Wolfram Alpha solution which @Omnomnomnom posts is unreasonably complicated for any practical purpose, it is justified to search for a simpler and computationally cheaper approximative solution.

Here is one way to approximate the elements in $\bf U$ and $\bf V$ matrices in the SVD.

Considering the matrix ${\bf M = M_1} + a {\bf M_2}$, where:

$${\bf M}(a) = {\bf U}(a){\bf \Sigma}(a) {\bf V}(a)^T$$

$${\bf M_1} = \begin{bmatrix}0&2&3&0&0\\6&7&1&0&0\end{bmatrix}, {\bf M_2} = \begin{bmatrix}0&0&0&4&5\\0&0&0&8&9\end{bmatrix}$$

We first set up the following set of functions (which we have found by experimentation)

$$f_N(a) =\exp\left[\frac{-a N^2}{1.5\cdot N_{max}}\right]$$

Exponential functions are cheap to calculate, they often have very optimized software functions or even hardware instructions in computers. The experiments below are $N_{max} = 8$, so max 8 exponential function evaluations needed for any given $a$.

Then we simply calculate SVD for a range of values, for example linearly spaced $ a \in [0,16]$ and we do linear regression on each element as a function of $a$:

$$\min_{\{c_{klm}\}}\left\| {\bf U}_{lm}(a) - \sum_{k=0}^{N_{max}} c_{klm} f_k(a)\right\|_2^2$$

[image]

[image]

[image]